# How to load default index file with .htaccess for variable directory structure in url

Tags: php, .htaccess

Lets say my site structure is like this:

```
www.mywebsite.com/directory/$variabledirectoryname/$variableproductlink
```

As you can see in the middle i have 2 variables in the url, but the last is the poduct link. My index.php file stays in www.mywebsite.com/directory/$variabledirectoryname folder. How to load it?
I have this code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php [L]
```

But it doesnt work.. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule in `/directory/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /directory/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/[^/]+/?$ $1/index.php [L]
```

---

**Update:**

You can use this rule in **root** `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(directory/[^/]+)/[^/]+/?$ $1/index.php [L]
```

Comment: #Anubhava Thanks for helping me ! Now I get Not Found page

Comment: yes, full 404, this is the header title: 404 Not Found

Comment: full url is www.site.com/directory/travel-agents/test345

Comment: index.php stays in travel-agents directory

Comment: htaccess is placed in the root directory. /directory/ and travel-agents are real folders on the server, just the last part test345 is the product link and it is not real folder..

Comment: ok that's the problem then. I mentioned clearly in answer that this .htaccess will go in `/directory/` not in root.

Comment: :) thats solved the problem Anubhava ! Isn't it possible to be commanded from root? Just asking, not so important, Huge thank you man !

Comment: #Anubhava can you please look at this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31532365/htaccess-to-load-index-file-for-url-with-variable-number-of-directories/31532853 thanks!

Comment: #anubhava, what if my index.php is in folder root/addbusiness and visitor visit this url: http://example.com/addbusiness/free ? How to load the index.php file? I tried with this:
RewriteBase /addbusiness/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/[^/]+/?$ $1/index.php [L] but it doesnt work, thanks !

Comment: Strange but still doesnt work even if I remove RewriteBase /addbusiness/

Comment: Hmm I guess then it is better to create a new question with relevant details we will attend it. Most of the times it is easy to fully understand a problem from comments.

Comment: I posted it as new question ! Thanks