# .htaccess to load index file for url with variable number of directories?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

lets say I have directory regions in my root:

```
root/regions
```

I want to load index.php file which is located in regions folder if user visits one of the following:

```
http://www.example.com/regions/united-kingdom
http://www.example.com/regions/united-kingdom/london
http://www.example.com/regions/united-kingdom/londom/rm8-16de
```

Country, city and post code dont exist as directory !
How to do that? 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `regions/.htaccess` you can have this .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /regions/

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: This is what I call Master ! :) thank you anubhava ! As good as always :)

Comment: Anubhava, can you please look at this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39014697/htaccess-how-to-load-index-file-from-specific-directory?noredirect=1

Answer (score 0):

The order should be DirectoryIndex index.html index.php // default is index.html.

If the webserver finds no files in the current directory that matches names in the DirectoryIndex directive, then a directory listing will be displayed to the browser, showing all files in the current directory. Apache will look for each of the above files, in order, and serve the first one it finds when a visitor requests just a directory.

Once check [DirectoryIndex](http://support.modwest.com/content/1/147/en/how-can-i-show-a-default-page-other-than-indexhtml.html) which is solution for you.

Let me know if you face any query/concern regarding this.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, thank you for helping me. I think your approach is wrong. DirectoryIndex index.html index.php will help only if I visit http://www.example.com/regions but for additional /countries/city/postcode it will not be able to help as they dont exists as folders and I will get error 500 if I try to visit.. Directory index is not hte solution !